# Angular JS assign class to body tag depending on view displayed?

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs

I have an angular application similar to this:

```
<html>
   <body ng-app="my-app" ngcloak ng-controller="MainCtrl">

     ...stuff...

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div ng-view=""></div>

     ....
```

And the view is set by Routes:

```
 .when('/maps', {
            templateUrl: 'views/maps.html',
            controller: 'MapsCtrl'
        })
```

It works fine.  What I'd like to know is how I can get a class from the current location, using the above example, assign a class "maps" to the body tag for page-specific CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup a listener in MainController like this:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
        $scope.routeClassName = $route.current.className;
    }
});
```

And in template:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-class="routeClassName">
```

Then you can configure routes like this:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/maps', {
    controller: 'mapsController',
    template: 'maps',
    className: 'maps'   // <--- class name
})
.when('/about', {
    controller: 'aboutController',
    template: 'about',
    className: 'about'  // <--- class name
})
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QUaw6SkgPfR4IPyKniXG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $location service to figure out the current location and then use ng-class to assign it to your body tag. e.g.

JS

```
var MainCtrl = function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$location = $location;
}
```

HTML

```
<body ng-class="{maps: '/maps' === '$location.path()'}"></body>
```