# Angular $locationProvider not changing .url()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Goal:** I am trying to add the value of `$location.url()` as an attribute of my `<body>` tag to add page specific styling. It should automatically change when the route changes.

**Expected behaviour:**

- When you first land on the page, the route is passed to the `<body>`
- When route changes, the new route gets passed to the `<body>`

**Observed behaviour:**

- When you first land on the page, the route is successfully passed to the `<body>`
- When the route changes, *the route in the `<body>` remains the same*

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'appData', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($scope, appData, $location, $rootScope) {

$scope.location = $location.url();

// Unrelated code follows...
```

**HTML**

```
<body data-page="{{ location }}" ng-controller="MainController">
```

Now from here I expect to be able to style it with `[data-page="/login"] {}` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is descriptive enough... Let me know if I should create a Plunker to better illustrate my problem

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944345/949476

Comment: It's similar to what I'm looking for, but not quite what I want. I would like to do it based on the route passed, not necessarily a hard-coded class name. Otherwise, I would just do `$scope.className = 'whatever-class'` in each controller

Comment: Almost the same: http://plnkr.co/edit/YEIGsl3li8ArhP3EJTlA?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the [`$routeChangeSuccess`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route#%24routeChangeSuccess) event. Here you could update your location each time.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    $rootScope.location = $location.url();
});
```

Comment: Boom perfect. I'd been playing with `$routeChangeSuccess` but it wasn't clicking. I didn't put the params in the `function()` because they weren't used.